# What's best practice for logging a django app on AWS?

Tags: django, logging, amazon-web-services

I'll be using a load balancer, so I'd like one place where all the logs go. A google search didn't come up with anything definitive. Wondering what others are doing.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to install [sentry](https://getsentry.com/welcome/) to keep your logs organized.